# Set default username and password for ftp client?

Tags: windows, linux, ftp

I have to ftp one server many times on day and I want to avoid retyping username and password.So I want to set default username and password for ftp client for spec ip/site, or configure the ftp daemon to make it keep ftp session as long as it could.

Is there any method for the first quesiton under windows and the second question under linux?

+clarify: I need something could do it within commandline.

thanks.

Comment: is ssh an option?  You could put your public key on the server & not  have to supply a password for either windows or linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [ncftp](http://www.ncftp.com) you can specify username on password, and also let you create bookmarks that include password. ncftpput/ncftpget are better options for scripting.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use FileZilla as a ftp client. Set a profile for this specific site. FileZilla works on both windows and linux.

Comment: @MrStatic:I'd like some commandline things.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a file which contains the username and password and reference it via the ftp command (-s:filename option in windowsXP) in the commandline. I dont know the exact syntax of the file that contains the username and password but i think this page may help.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/how-to-automate-ftp-uploads-from-the-windows-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [CrossFTP](http://www.crossftp.com/) client, available on Windows, Linux and Mac.
The freeware version has Favorites, among many other features.